# Pjax update multiple blocks Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I learn Yii2 and I decided to get acquainted with the work of technology Pjax on site: http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial/. There is example "Multiple blocks". But it is implemented as a example version, and is not quite correct. It is written below. In this example in one action *actionMultiple* calculating *string* and *key* in one place, but it must be relised into different actions. So I decided to do it right but collided with the problem that when I click on the link it redirect me to a new page with the generation of a string or key. I need to do it in same page without reloading.

Controller:

```
public function actionMultiple()
    {
        $security = new Security();
        $randomString = $security->generateRandomString();
        $randomKey = $security->generateRandomKey();
        return $this->render('multiple', [
            'randomString' => $randomString,
            'randomKey' => $randomKey,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionString()
    {
        $security = new Security();
        $randomString= $security->generateRandomString();
        return $this->render('_randomString', [
            'randomString' => $randomString,
        ]);
    }
    public function actionKey()
    {
        $security = new Security();
        $randomKey = $security->generateRandomKey();
        return $this->render('_randomKey', [
            'randomKey' => $randomKey,
        ]);
    }
```

view multiple:

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Html;

?>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= Html::a("Generate Random String", ['site/string'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
    <h3><?= $randomString ?></h3>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= Html::a("Generate Random Key", ['site/key'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
    <h3><?= $randomKey ?><h3>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

view _randomString:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

?>

<?= Html::a("Generate Random String", ['site/string'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
<h3><?= $randomString ?></h3>
```

view _randomKey:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

?>

<?= Html::a("Generate Random Kay", ['site/key'], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary']) ?>
<h3><?= $randomKey ?><h3>
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: if you are using pjax there is no need of other views except `multiple.php`. in all actions inside controller render `multiple` view only

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice